# Should I use the Authorization header for API keys

Tags: api, rest, authorization, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

We're going to expose a custom built API (.NET) through Azure API Management. We want to conform to well-known standards where ever possible, so we don't surprise our API consumers. The API is secured through an API key which users generate from APIM's Developer Portal.

My understanding is that the Authorization header should be used for authentication and authorization purposes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

But strangely, API-Key is not included as an authentication scheme.

https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml#authschemes

Should API consumers use an authorization header to authenticate?

E.g. `Authorization: API-Key xxx-xxx`

Or a custom header.

E.g. `my-key:xxx-xxx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you shouldn't need any API-key if you have a token in the authorization header. I assume API-key/client and secret key are already used to generate a token. When the client sends token via an authorization header, the API owner validates your token and returns a response.